# Inserting a Gridview Row after 10 items

Tags: android, gridview

I have no idea how to achieve this. I want to insert a row after 10th position of item in GridView. I have no idea from where to I start this. [image: I want to do like this]

Thanks and please give some advice.

Comment: are you using recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager?

Comment: @prashant17 I am using ExpandableHeightGridView.

Comment: Recycler view would be a safe bet I guess. Explandableheighgridview cannot add another row. Else you might have to tweak in UI by adding a RelativeLayout on top but I wouldn't do that.

Comment: @sanjeev - so how can i do this using RecyclerView, any idea pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:** Define two layout item one for column and other one for row

**Step 2:** Create recycler view adapter , and override below methods

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int viewType;
    if ((position + 1) % 10 == 0) {
        viewType = VIEW_TYPE_ROW;
    } else {
        viewType = VIEW_TYPE_COLUMN;
    }
    return viewType;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    /**
     * Optimization of notifyDataSetChanged
     * Look at documentation for setHasStableIds(true) and getItemId(int position)
     */
    return STABLE_ID + position;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_COLUMN:
             // inflate coloumn layout and view holder
             break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_ROW:
             // inflate row layout and view holder
             break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_COLUMN:
             break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_ROW:
             break;
    }
}
```

While initialzing adapter do like below

```
    final GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 2);
    layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            switch (themeAdapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
                case ThemeAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_COLUMN:
                    return 1;
                case ThemeAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_ROW:
                    return layoutManager.getSpanCount();
                default:
                    return layoutManager.getSpanCount();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here themeAdapter is your RecyclerView adapter.

Comment: Interesting. ThemeAdapter is ReclerViewAdapter right?

Comment: @sanjeev Thank you !! Yeah it works I have the same implementation

Answer (score 1):

If you use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` you can use `setSpanSizeLookup`

You need an `adapter` with `multiviewtype`

```
mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            switch(adapter.getItemViewType(position)){
                case adapter.TYPE_ROW:
                    return 2;
                case adapter.TYPE_COLUMN:
                    return 1;
            }
        }
    });
```